# python logging can't work when start a new process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come across a strange question about `logging` library when using `multiprocessing`.

First example (wrong):

```py
import multiprocessing
import logging
import time


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = None
        self.v = "v1"

    def run(self):
        # start a new process here
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.work, name="sub-process")
        p.start()

    def work(self):
        i = 0
        # print info of logger object 
        print(f"v: {self.v}; logger: {self.logger}; handler:{self.logger.handlers}")
        while True and i < 10:
            name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
            self.logger.info(f"current name: {name} + v : {self.v}")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            i += 1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.v = "v2"
        
        # if init logger object inside class
        # then something wrong happens...
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        ch = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s(): %(message)s'))
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

        self.logger = logger
        self.logger.info("B init success")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.run()
```

and it outputs incorrectly:

```py
B init success   # this line is the output of logger in __init__
v: v2; logger: <RootLogger root (WARNING)>; handler: []   # this line is the output of print function in work
```

We can see that `logger` has changed to **raw root** logger object(with default `WARNING` and empty handler) while in `work` method.

But things go well when I change the **location of init of logger**.

```py
import multiprocessing
import logging
import time

# if init logger object outside class
# then all goes well
logger = logging.getLogger()
ch = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s(): %(message)s'))
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = None
        self.v = "v1"

    def run(self):
        # start a new process here
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.work, name="sub-process")
        p.start()

    def work(self):
        i = 0
        # print info of logger object
        print(f"v: {self.v}; logger: {self.logger}; handler:{self.logger.handlers}")
        while True and i < 10:
            name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
            self.logger.info(f"current name: {name} + v : {self.v}")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            i += 1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.v = "v2"

        self.logger = logger
        self.logger.info("B init success")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.run()
```

And this time, the outputs are correct!(the `logger` object is just I define in code)

```py
B init success
# the following line is output of print function
current name: sub-process + v : v2
v: v2; logger: <RootLogger root (DEBUG)>; handler:[<FileHandler /Users/zjj/test.log (DEBUG)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
current name: sub-process + v : v2
```

But, in my project,I have to init the logger object until I get some parameters from `__init__` method, is there a way to fix this problem(the wrong version)?

Thanks!

Comment: on Linux Mint both versions give the same result with `v: v2; logger: <RootLogger root (DEBUG)>; handler:[<FileHandler /Users/zjj/test.log (DEBUG)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]`

Comment: I confirm the first script gives the "wrong" results under Windows and it works as expected on Raspian. Under Windows, in work method, we are using a different logger, confirmed by print(id(self.logger)). In Raspbian, the id's are the same. No idea why.

Comment: My system is m1 Mac, so it's system-wise. Mac and Windows will give wrong results, linux system may do right.